# Dotty 0.19 (Scala 3) features: contextual abstractions

Tags: scala, extension-methods

**tl;dr**

I tried to write some as general and as feasible as possible code where entities are able to communicate with other entities of the same type or of different types, allowing for the recipient to reply to the sender.

**Details :**

- Trying to work with some of the new contextual abstractions e.g. given and extension methods
- Have a general Entity type to enable sending and receiving messages
- To be able to send message types different from what I can receive.
- To have the ability to reply to a received message
- To be able to send messages between 2 instances of the same type `T` given the presence of `Entity[T, TMsg]`
- To be able to send messages between different types `T` and `U` given the presence of both `Entity[T, TMsg]` and `Entity[U, UMsg]`
- Have a `Person` example capable of receiving Strings that can do all this

**Concerns I have regarding the code :**

- Feels more complex, more difficult to understand than it needs to be
- Type parameters are often just single character ones, but I felt like it would render the code totally unreadable, now however I have very long type signatures

**The code**

```
trait Entity[Me, InMsg] 
  def (me: Me) send[Receiver, OutMsg] (receiver: Receiver, msg: OutMsg) (given Entity[Receiver, OutMsg], Entity[Me, InMsg]): Unit
  def (me: Me) receive[Sender, ReplyMsg] (sender: Sender, msg: InMsg) (given Entity[Sender, ReplyMsg]): Unit
  def (me: Me) name(): String

class Person(private val name: String)

object Person

  given Entity[Person, String]

    def (me: Person) send[Receiver, OutMsg] (receiver: Receiver, msg: OutMsg) (given Entity[Receiver, OutMsg], Entity[Person, String]): Unit = 
      receiver.receive[Person, String](me, msg)

    def (me: Person) receive[Sender, ReplyMsg] (sender: Sender, msg: String) (given Entity[Sender, ReplyMsg]): Unit = 
      println(f"I'm ${me.name} and I just RECEIVED a msg saying $msg from ${sender.name()}")

    def (me: Person) name () = 
      me.name

@main def m = Person("AAA").send(Person("BBB"), "Hi")
```

Comment: What is your code supposed to achieve? It isn't clear in your post, you should edit it to explain well... why you wrote this code.

Comment: @IEatBagels added a short description, do you find it clearer now? Thx

Comment: I have a couple more questions that'll make the post clearer, if you don't mind. You say "What I attempted", did it work? The phrasing makes it sound like you didn't achieve your goal and the code doesn't work. Do you feel like your title is as precise as it could be? Do you think there's a specific pattern that exists that does the same thing you're trying to do (I think there is) that you could name that would help pinpoint the exact goal?

Comment: Yes, it did work, although not extensively tested I've seen it work. I didn't realise that I'm implying that it might not have worked, feel free to suggest better wording.

Comment: The title describes an aspect of what's in the code, of course I'd like to get reviews that are not limited to this single aspect, such as how idiomatic the code is, or the concerns I listed that are not directly linked to the title.

Comment: This can be done in multiple ways, I don't see any specific pattern coupled with the issue. I went for this typeclass-like one, for this exercises the new syntax I wanted to try out.

Comment: Alright this looks good! Good job on your first post and, especially, good job on being to keen to answer and edit your post, this shows an openness that is important on StackExchange :)

Answer (score 1):

First, a minor thing here:

```
def (me: Me) send[Receiver, OutMsg] (receiver: Receiver, msg: OutMsg) (given Entity[Receiver, OutMsg], Entity[Me, InMsg]): Unit
```

The second `given` parameter is actually redundant - it's literally the same type as  `this`, and with contextual parameters, there shouldn't be any other instance.

In fact, implementation of `send` in `Person` shows that you can have a default impl:

```
def (me: Me) send[Receiver, OutMsg] (receiver: Receiver, msg: OutMsg) (given Entity[Receiver, OutMsg]): Unit =
  receiver.receive(me, msg)(given this)
```

---

Next, something more subtle:

```
def (me: Me) receive[Sender, ReplyMsg] (sender: Sender, msg: InMsg) (given Entity[Sender, ReplyMsg]): Unit
```

Whoever is implementing this will have to support *any* `ReplyMsg`, and therefore won't be able to create one (without breaking type system by casting or nulls). Try implementing it in a way that sends something back - you won't be able to make a call to `send` compile with normal code. If it's desirable, you can simplify the signature using existentials:

```
def (me: Me) receive[Sender] (sender: Sender, msg: InMsg) (given Entity[Sender, ?]): Unit
```

But I think it's not, as you wanted to reply to things. You'll have to work out a way to make it work - the simplest one being having 3 parameters - `Entity[Me, In, Out]` and accepting something that has `Me[Other, Out, In]`.